# writing generic-type objects to file java

Tags: java, file, object, generics

Is it even possible? I need to be able to read from the file later on.
example of what I intend doing (but doesn't work because E isn't Serializable):

```
private <E> void writeEvent(ObjectOutputStream out,E obj) throws IOException{
        out.writeObject(new custEvent(obj));
        }

class custEvent<E> implements Serializable{
        private E obj;
        private Date date;

        public custEvent(E obj) {
            this.obj=obj;
            date=new Date();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to actually do here?

Comment: Save the component and time it was clicked to a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use use an upper bound in your generic parametrization for `E`?

As in:

```
private <E extends Serializable> void writeEvent(ObjectOutputStream out,E obj) {
  // etc.
}
```

The confusion here would be that `Serializable` is an interface and cannot be "extended" by classes (but it **can** be extended by other interfaces as Thomas remarks), but the upper bound is still valid.

Of course this implies that your `E`s will **need** to implement `Serializable`, or implement an interface that extends `Serializable`.

Comment: Well other interfaces _can_ extend interfaces ;)

Comment: @Thomas aha true! Let me reformulate :)